# Write the initial Django SQL to a file?

Tags: sql, django, bash

I'm starting a new Django app and I'm generating the DB with `python manage.py syncdb`.

Now I know that `python manage.py sql myproject` returns the SQL that's used to create all the tables etc. but the SQL returned is too big to Copy+Paste into a file.

Is there a way to write the output of this command into a seperate SQL file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may redirect your output onto a file:

```
python manage.py sql myproject > initial.sql
```